# Пожалуйста помогите исправить ошибку

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int one, two;
    string s;
    int a = 1;
    while(a = 1)
        cin >> one;
        cin >> s;
        cin >> two;

        if (s = "+") {
            cout << one + two << endl;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка - секрет? Их тут как минимум три, кстати.

Comment: Так ты ответ знаешь???

Comment: @Magprone работа над ошибками: 1) не задавайте вопросов, связанных с помощью в исправлении ошибки, которые не содержат описания проблемы и желаемого поведения. 2) равенство обозначается как ==. 3) если в стандартный поток ввода ввести неверные значения (те которые сейчас не ожидаются для ввода), то это приведет к инвалидации потока и невозможности считывать какие-либо значения.

Answer (score 3):

Типичная ошибка.

Оператор присваивания `!=` оператор сравнения.

В си, `c++` для сравнения данных используется двойное равно, т.е. `==`, в то время как для присваивания, используется одно равно т.е.:

```
int some_int = 100; // = — это оператор присваивания
```

Для сравнения необходимо писать `==`:

```
int some_int = 100;
int some_other_int == 101;

if(some_int == some_other_int) // == — это оператор сравнения
{
    ...
}
```

Если вы не знаете таких простых вещей, то вам стоит почитать обо всех операторах [сравнения](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) `c++`.